# Apprequest of Android Facebook sdk 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, apprequests

I am using the updated Facebook SDK V3.0 final for Android. I am trying to send app requests to facebook frineds who do not have the application. The code is:

```
public void fbookinvite(){

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", "X");
        postParams.putString("message", "DOWNLOAD X.");

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        postParams.putString("access_token", session.getAccessToken());

        if (session==null||session.getState().isClosed()){
            System.out.println("session is null");
        }else{
            //meaning we are good to go.
            Request request = new Request(session,"/friend facebook id/apprequests", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                    System.out.println("response was: "+response.toString());
                }

            });

            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
        }       
    }
```

When the code runs I get one of the following from the printed response:

```
responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#2) Failed to create any app request}, isFromCache:false
```

... or:

```
Response:  responseCode: unknown, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: null}, isFromCache:false}
```

I have the following permissions: `publist_stream` and `publish_actions`.

After solving the problem I'd also like to know how to add a group of recipients to the app request.

I do not want to use the Facebook dialog.

Comment: I wish to make an invitations containing links to app page on google play store and apple appstore to send by users to their friends who do not yet have the application, and I wish to do that without the use of the facebook web dialog. How do I do those?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
        Bundle params = new Bundle();   
        params.putString("message",
                "Learn how to make your Android apps social");
        params.putString("to", "YOUR_FRIEND_UID_HERE");
        WebDialog requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(
                this, Session.getActiveSession(), params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                            FacebookException error) {
                        // your code here 
                    }

                }).build();
        requestsDialog.show();
```

This is the proper way to send an app request explicitly to someone.  If you do not include the `to` parameter, the user can choose who they want to send to.

Comment: How do I do that without the dialog? I do not want the user to have to see the facebook dialog and press send. Also, when I do that it goes directly to the user's android app and not the user's facebook incoming messages. I want it to be an invitation to use the app, including the url to the google play page where it is located. Using the suggested above code, users who have the app just get a message and opening it launches the app, and those who don't have it just get a blank white screen from the facebook app.

Comment: There's no way to do it without the dialog.

Comment: Not even with the graph api? is there at least a way to make the webdialog automaticaly send without it showing? or another way of hiding it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Response:  responseCode: unknown, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: null}, isFromCache:false}
```

This is a scenario usually related with running simultaneous FB requests on your own threads.
I learnt the hard way to use either

```
Request.executeAsync()
```

or

```
RequestAsyncTask
```